# Backward model selection in metanalysis using 'glmulti' and/or 'metafor'

Tags: mixed-model, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I want to test with a full model testing significant interactions with the main predictor `'Nadd'` for my log transformed response ratio (`'MSA'`):

```
MSA ~ (MAT + MAP + MST + Ndep + Duration + Fert)*Nadd + (1|Experiment)
```

There is a wrapper function in 'glmulti' that allow to filter out undesired interactions from the full model. However but I cannot account for the random-effect. This is the code with the model fitted with `glm` (modified from [Vincent Calcagno's blog](https://vcalcagnoresearch.wordpress.com/package-glmulti/), author of glmulti)

```
mydata<-msadat%>%select(MSA,N,MAT,MAP,MST,Ndep,Duration,Fert)
nullos <- glm(MSA~1,data=mydata)
summary(nullos)

myglm=function(MSA, data) {
  if (missing(data)) data<-environment(MSA)
  termz = terms(MSA,data=data)
  orderz = attr(termz,"order")
  intz = which(orderz==2)
  index=which(dimnames(attr(termz,"factors"))[[1]] == "Nadd")
  if (length(index)>0) { # the desired effect must be present
    if(length(intz)>0) {
      # we simply test that all interactions include the desired effect
      # otherwise we return the crappy null model
      if (min(attr(termz,"factors")[index,intz])==0) return(nullos)
    }
  } else return(nullos);
  return(glm(formula=MSA, data=data)) 
}

glmulti(MSA~., data=mydata, fitfunc=myglm)
```

The problem is that I don't want to use `glm()`. I want a mixed-effect linear model and with this code I cannot select the `'Experiment'` factor. Plus, I would like to use `nlme` or `lme4` for model selection.

Can you suggest me an alternative? Would you suggest to do the selection manually comparing models with LRT? For example:

```
res.a <- rma(MSA, Variance, mods = ~ Nadd + Fert, random=~1 | Experiment, data=msadat, method="ML")
res.i <- rma(MSA, Variance, mods = ~ Nadd * Fert, random=~1 | Experiment, data=msadat, method="ML")
anova(res.a, res.i)
```

Comment: Without more details this is going to be hard to answer but (a) in general comparing models on the basis of theoretical concerns is preferred (b) I think you have the wrong function from metafor, you probably want rma.mv.

Comment: Thanks mdewey. I admit it, indeed my question is not very precise. I am studying 'metafor' documentation now and these stuff makes much more sense.

Comment: I am in the same situation. Could you please specify the function you used to incorporate a particular set of interactions to run with a rma model in glmulti?

Answer (score 2):

The issues involved in using meta-analytic methods with the R glmutil package are discussed in this web page http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:model_selection_with_glmulti by Wolfgan Viechtbauer. It is a substantial document too long to summarise adequately here.

This question would perhaps have been more on topic on the R list dedicated to meta-analysis https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// where questions about coding and statistical methods are welcome.